# Looking for a strategy to optimize a big body field on a node

Tags: 8, nodes, entities, caching

I'm using Drupal 8.4.x

I have just one node with a big text on its body field (about 2.5 MB). Looking a strategy to optimize:

1. *Page load.* Does exist any "content lazy loading" module? (I can see [one for D7](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodelazyloader) but without a stable release).
2. I'll like to create *revisions* on this node. I'm gonna use [Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module to see changes and also to enable visitors to see those changes. This a consuming task on a big node and not sure how to cache/optimize those Diffs.

*Note:* I've tought about spliting the content in different nodes (like a book) and then use something like [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) but I'll find hard to implement 2 with this aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module is probably the current go-to solution for a more manageable setup than a large body field. Functionally, it's right in between a single text field and completely separate nodes. It enables you to create more manageable chunks of content that replace the traditional body field. Each chunk can be simple text, or more complex things. Each "paragraph" is an entity with fields, and the node references those entities. When editing, it feels like a more focused interface. The content creator stays on the node, so the complexity is hidden in the background.

Another strength it has is good support for revisions. In fact, it requires the Entity Reference Revisions module, and its project page suggests using the Diff module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm sure it will be clear for the editor/content creator and great to know that it supports revisions and diff. How to handle 1.? I'll suppose that is possible to create a View of paragraphs and use Views infite scroll in order to lazy load the content and increase page load speed?

Comment: @Yaazkal I think you're right, that using a view to lazy-load the paragraph items will be what is needed. The Views Infinite Scroll (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module can take care of the lazy loading. It's well supported and has a stable release, currently at 1.5. Everything I see related to lazy loading is for images, videos, iframes, etc. Not for arbitrary content. It would be cool to have a lazy-load paragraphs field formatter, but I don't think one exists yet.

Comment: thanks so much for the suggestion. Paragraphs made the administration of the big content pretty easy; it is now much faster for the editor to manage the content of the node. By now it's an easy fix and I'll look forward how to make it interesting from the user perspective. Happy new year!